# Using cross reference roles in the Python domain in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I am failing to understand the use of cross reference roles in the Python domain, specifically **:py:const:** Can someone please provide a clearer explanation and an example of it's use?

For example, I have a file module.rst which contains the following directives:

```
.. default-role:: any
.. automodule:: CommonSymbols
       :members:

:py:const: Success
:py:mod: CommonSymbols
```

From the documentation I would have expected :py:const: SUCCESS, where SUCCESS is a variable defined in module CommonSymbols to generate a link to the definition of SUCCESS in CommonSymbols. Similarly, I would have expected a link to the module CommonSymbols when :py:mod: CommonSymbols was encountered.

Instead I get the following output for the two roles in my displayed HTML:

```
:py:const: Success :py:mod: CommonSymbols
```

This is totally useless and is the reason that I asked how these roles actually work.

Comment: The syntax is wrong. The target of a cross-reference needs to be enclosed in backticks, like this: ``:py:mod:`CommonSymbols` ``.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation under cross-referencing Python objects for [:py:const:](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#role-py:const):

> The name enclosed in this markup can include a module name and/or a class name. For example,

```
:py:func:`filter`
```

> could refer to a function named filter in the current module, or the built-in function of that name.

Try:

```
:py:const:`CONSTANT`
```

Comment: As you can see from my edited question this markup does not appear to do anything useful.

Comment: You're mixing blocks in your example. The syntax I provided works when you are defining a reference to a stand-alone Python `constant` object. For your edited question, you will need to include the `autodoc` extension in your `conf.py`, then in your reST indent the fields. I don't know whether constants are supported in the fields. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html